# Check data type in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to check data types in spark and create two RDDs after it. One RDD with validated records and another one with the errors.

I was thinking to create the following methods:

```
def isInt (value: Any): Option[Int] = {
    case value: Int => Some(value)
    case _ => None
}
```

And later I can call this methods depending on the column and if I get None, give the error, something like:

```
rdd.map{
     case(age) => if isInt(age).isEmpty (age,ErrorCodes.NOT_INT) else ((Int)age, None)
}
```

But I found two problems in this approach:

1. I have 150 columns, so it is not so elegant to call this methods for each field.
2. If one field changes, I must change my code, so it is not so flexible.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Iterate each column in loop then validate per type of the column. Based on validation result filter main to divide it into 2 rdds.

Comment: This might be a case of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you're trying to identify the types of RDD entries, which means your RDD "lost" its strong typing (is `rdd` in the question an instance of `RDD[Any]`?) - how did that happen? RDDs are best kept with a known and consistent type. Perhaps you should do the filtering _before_ you end up with an RDD of unknown type.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the context, the most principled approach to this sort of thing (I want good values and errors) is probably to create an RDD of Either.  For example:

```
import scala.util.{ Either, Left, Right }

case class NotAnInt(obj: Any)

def maybeIntRDD(anyRDD: RDD[Any]): RDD[Either[NotAnInt, Int]] =
   anyRDD.map {
     case i: Int => Right(i)
     case x => Left(NotAnInt(x))
   }

val eitherRDD: RDD[Either[NotAnInt, Int]] = maybeIntRDD(rdd)

// Get the ints and not ints
val intRDD: RDD[Int] = eitherRDD.flatMap(_.right.toOption)
val notIntRDD: Rdd[NotAnInt] = eitherRDD.flatMap(_.left.toOption)

// Double the ints, keep the NotAnInts
val doubled: RDD[Either[NotAnInt, Int]] = eitherRDD.map(_.right.map(_ * 2))
```

If you have a lot of columns, it may be useful to have a ValidationFailure trait with some case classes or case objects extending that trait for the different types of failures

```
def validateRow(row: YourColumnsTypeHere): Either[Seq[ValidationFailure], YourColumnTypeHere] = {
  // validation logic here, with errors accumulating in the failures Seq
  if (isValid)
    Right(row)
  else
    Left(failures)
}

val classifiedRDD = rdd.map(row => validateRow(row))
```